# Expand Adam Shaw's Full Calendar to show Years and Months

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm looking at using Adam Shaw's excellent Fullcalendar in an application.  Their is a requirement however to show multiple years as a view and multiple months as a view.  I can't immediately see how I can tailor Fullcalendar to achieve this.

I can see the AvailableViews (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/Available_Views/) could the answer, but unfortunately the documentation doesn't suggest why the next steps maybe if someone wished to expand this.

Suggestions on where to start looking, or any code snippets would be appreciated.

Help, as always, is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems someone has implemented a yearly view using multiple month views, and is providing the code [here](http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=871). I believe this could answer your question!

Comment: Good lord! That is quite something.  Thanks so much Andrei. +1. :)

Comment: @Andrei the link in your answer uses version 1.5 , Is there any help for the latest release?