# Year view calendar

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I need a calendar like [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) but with full year view. The idea is that every user can select his own holidays using this calendar and store all the individual days withing a database.

Does someone know any library or something for that?

Comment: please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087537/what-are-some-free-web-based-open-source-calendar-solutions

Comment: no one of the refered has full year selectable view..

Comment: may be this one help for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10949486/year-view-in-fullcalendar-jquery-plugin      http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=871                                                          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362188/expand-adam-shaws-full-calendar-to-show-years-and-months

Comment: I already tried them. The have year view, but ther is no way to select through them

Comment: The [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/) plugin from @snowp's SO link seems to provide selectable dates from what I can tell. You could use [`selectable`](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/selection/select_method/) to select dates programmatically, use the [`select callback`](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/selection/select_callback/) to perform your own function after selection, and use the [`selectable option`](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/selection/selectable/) to allow multi-day events. Perhaps I am misunderstanding something though?

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution of you question. this may be helpful to you
http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/#about

```
('#date3').DatePicker({
    flat: true,
    date: ['2008-07-28','2008-07-31'],
    current: '2008-07-31',
    calendars: 3,
    mode: 'range',
    starts: 1
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a followup answer to your comment . You can choose a full calander by using this code .
this is the `jqueryUI datepicker` code for showing multiple months at a time .

```
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
          numberOfMonths: 12,
          showButtonPanel: true
        });
```

This will do it for you .